# MAG3110 and MPU6050 on one I2C bus connected to a Raspberry Pi

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi, i2c, bus

I am trying to use separate pre-built breakout modules containing a [MAG3110](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MAG3110.pdf) (Magnetometer) ([module](http://www.bajdi.com/mag3110-magnetometer-and-arduino/)) and a [MPU6050](https://www.invensense.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf) (gyroscope) ([GY-521 module](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050)) on one I2C bus connected to a Raspberry Pi. Although both devices have different addresses (0x0e) and (0x68), I cannot get them both working at the same time.

If I connect each of them alone, both work perfectly. If I connect each of them together with another module ([PCF8591](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCF8591.pdf) ADC + DAC) on the I2C bus, everything is fine.

However when both MAG3110 and MPU6050 modules are on the same bus, I only see the MPU6050 (0x68) using `i2cdetect`.

Does anyone have an idea what is happening here?

Comment: (a) Please edit your question & add a full schematic (excluding the RPi) and close-up in-focus photos of your hardware. (b) I suspect you are not just using those ICs "bare", but are probably using pre-made *modules* which contain those ICs and also pull-up resistors and perhaps level-translation functionality. If so, please add links to the data for those modules. (c) Do you have access to an oscilloscope? If so, have you looked at the rise/fall times of the I2C signals for each test? (d) Have you investigated the total effective pull-up resistance for the I2C signals, in each of your tests?

Comment: Hi Sam,thanks for your quick reply (a) I will post a picture later on, but the schematic is straight forward.  (b)  You are right, I am using breakout board: GY-521 for the MPU6050 (sorry, that was my typo in the original post), decribed here: https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050 and for the MAG3110, I am using: http://www.bajdi.com/mag3110-magnetometer-and-arduino/.

Comment: (c) oscilloscope ist not available but I have a logic analyzer at hand. (d) that hint was very userful, as the description in the link above for the MPU6050 mentions some problems with the pull-ups on the board I am using. I will investigate in that direction.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. (e) Please clarify: In paragraph 2, instead of "*If I connect each of them [...]*", I *think* you mean "*If I connect both of them [...]*". (a) Now that you have confirmed you are using pre-built modules, the schematic is more complicated than you think - you probably don't even have the full schematic for each of those modules. You will need to examine and reverse-engineer each of them, especially regarding the pull-up resistors. (c) Unfortunately a normal logic analyser cannot show the rise/fall times, which are affected by the effective total pull-up resistors :-(

Comment: Yes, seems a pretty complicated setup. To clarify (e): MAG3110 + PCF8591 Breakout Boards work on the same bus. MPU6050 an PCF8591 Breakout Boards work on the same bus. Only MPU6050 and MAG3110 do not. In this case, only the MPU6050 is visible.

Comment: You're going to need to figure out the internals of those boards.  What's worse, they may have partial 5v translation logic in there (in different ways) for Arduino use, which depending on how it is done can cause problems in an all 3.3v project.

Comment: I am trying to get some schematics for both. What is making me think, is that both work with other modules only when I connect both at a time there is the problem.

Comment: @MarcGutekunst - Thanks. I've updated the question with the new info from your comments. Please check and make sure I haven't misinterpreted anything. You can edit your question to correct it, if needed. As *Chris* & I have said, you need to examine the exact details of the various modules you are using (beware: a schematic you find online *might not* apply to your specific boards e.g. resistor values can vary on different breakout boards with the same part number like your GY-521). "*only when I connect both at a time there is the problem*" Yes, it's common with I2C h/w design issues.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely culprits

a) both boards have built-in pull-ups, which makes it too strong when you connect them simultaneously. Solution: locate and remove pull-ups from one of the boards. Note that many boards (e.g. Sparkfun ones) have solder jumpers between resistors and VCC, in which case you wouldn't need to remove resistors, simply remove the jumpers.

b) one or both boards have built-in level shifters that complicate matters, especially considering both sensors and RPi work at 3.3V already. Solution: hack the modules to remove LDOs and shifters. Connect incoming 3.3V and IO lines directly to corresponding PCB traces. Leave 2 pull-ups on one board or remove all of them and have your own external pull-ups.

Update: if your PCF8591 module is anything like [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/5pcs-PCF8591-AD-DA-converter-module-analog-to-digital-to-analog-conversion-For-Arduino/32668315883.html) it also has built-in pull-ups. It's amazing how many manufacturers make those permanent without considering that *maybe* the reason for using I2C is to have several devices on few pins. In short, if you get to hacking boards do this one as well. Then you can mix them in any combination with external pull-ups.